# When I try to publish my program in Visual Basic it gives me the installation files but does not update the .exe file in the debug folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, publishing

When I try to publish my program in Visual Basic it gives me the installation files but does not update the .exe file in the debug folder, what is happening? What can I do? I have already reinstalled VB but that did not help. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .exe before publishing?

Comment: Perhaps your installation/build target is not "Debug," and as a result it is deploying the resultant .EXE to a different folder? Or, perhaps there are no changes when you opt to publish, thus there would be no changes to the executable...

Answer (score 0):

Does publishing generate a Release build? Try checking the Release folder instead.

Comment: I did and it's there but it's an old file. I just published it, and it says the last time it was modified was yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your application the .exe file becomes .exe.deploy and extracted to the users computer at installation time. The .exe file in your debug and release folder is not updated because publish makes a release build in a temporary directory and then copies it to .exe.deploy file.

These are findings from my research about your issue and I can confirm that this is the case with the default visual studio settings. However your configuration may be different.

Hope this helps...